# Samsung galaxy S3 GT-I9300 4.3 Jelly Bean to 5.0-lollipop

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, updates, 5.0-lollipop, 4.3-jelly-bean

I would like to know if it is possible to update my Samsung Galaxy S3, which is in 4.3 Jelly Bean, to 5.0-lollipop. And in this case, I would like to know :

- If it is a good idea ;
- Will my phone support it ;
- What benefits it might bring me if it is possible.

I also would like to know the best way to proceed, to update my phone.

Thank you in advance.

Edit : I have a friend that has the same phone, and his phone updated itself. Why not mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it's a good idea.
2. Yes, your phone will support it. I've seen ROMs for the S3 (i9300) up to 5.0.2.
3. Benefits include: security fixes, better stability, improved battery life, new features and a lot more!

To update your phone, I would suggest

- rooting it (there's a lot of information on rooting over at the [XDA Developers Forum](http://www.xda-developers.com/),
- flashing a custom recovery like [CWM](https://www.clockworkmod.com/), and
- installing a custom 5.0.2 ROM. There are lots of them on XDA, so I'd spend a little time having a read up on the various functionality available.

As for why your friend got the update: it's possible that he has flashed a custom 5.0.0+ ROM also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found very clear tutos to update the S3. I will try it later and share my experience. Just for information my friend didn't flashed anything, his phone proposed him automatically few days ago.

Comment: @Maxime No problem. I'd like to hear how you get on! I haven't used my old Galaxy S3 for a long time; thus cannot verify whether there is a Stock Update. It's possible that you will also receieve one soon (could be a slightly different model for the rollout procedure). I think you will find many benefits from using a custom rom nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

**Not recommanded!**
I tried it days ago on I9300 and the phone goes horribly wrong with some 5.x *Lollipop* specially 5.1.x :

- **Bugs** and glitchs.
- **Heating** problems.
- **Battery life** problems.
- App **crashs**...

I tested more than one 5.x ROM (Based one CM12,CM12.1,...) on it and the same result every time!! but it work so much better on i9305(with 2GB of RAM). for that i think it could be a **memory problem**. That's why, i recommande the *stock* 4.3 updated ROM or a 4.4.x *kitkat* instead..

---

Maybe you can try and share your results, but dont forgot to backup your Data first.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts - thanks for taking your time to answer a question. It is however often useful to include links and references as sources for your answer. The current answer is just a suggestion based on your experience - there is nothing wrong with it but it would help if you add details - like which ROM have you been using - what problems were you having and is the developer aware of these problems.

Comment: i'll **keep that in mind** :) but i tested more than one 5.x *ROM* on my ex-i9300 and the same result every time!! but it work so much better on i9305. for that i think it could be a memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would not recommend it. My i9300 had a lot of trouble running 5.0.2 (CM12) smoothly. Furthermore, batterylife decreased severely up to the point that the phone even discharged noticeably when actively used whilst charging. I ended up restoring a backup to 4.4 after two days of use.

Comment: I have an i9300 that runs CM12 and have no problems at all.